# How do I add dynamic spacing between controls? (with pics)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout

My question is simple. What is the best way to achieve what you see the pic below in WPF?

At the moment this is a horizontal StackPanel, with the right padding of the checkbox set to 90. This works okay, but if you resize the window it's no good anymore, unless maybe you re-adjust the padding in the window's resize event, but that seems clunky when using a layout manager.

I am coming from a Qt background, and in Qt I would use a "stretch" element between the buttons and the checkbox to push them apart dynamically. Is there a similar concept in WPF? If not, how do I achieve this so that it will support dynamic resizing?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the corrent [`Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx) implementation, in this case a [`Grid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) would work best:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <CheckBox>Details</CheckBox>
    <Button Grid.Column="1">Exit</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="2">Reset</Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Idd, grid is the way to go :)

Come to think it, that and the canvas are ussually the only panel types I ever use :S